# What is the difference between using and not using using statement with DbContext [code first]?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, idisposable

I'm wondering what the difference between...

```
using (var db = new PteDotNetContext())
            {
                var blog = new Blog() { BlogType = 1, Title = "Blog 1", Description = TestInfo.UniqueRecordIdentifier, DateAdded = DateTime.Now, User = TestInfo.UniqueRecordIdentifier };
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }


            PteDotNetContext context2 = new PteDotNetContext();
            var blog2 = new Blog() { BlogType = 1, Title = "Blog 2", Description = TestInfo.UniqueRecordIdentifier, DateAdded = DateTime.Now, User = TestInfo.UniqueRecordIdentifier };
            context2.Blogs.Add(blog2);
            context2.SaveChanges();
```

is. I understand that using a using statement basically calls the destructor on the object. I just wonder...

a) Does the using statement open and then close a Sql connection on the DbContext?
b) If so what happens with the second statement because i never actually opened it and it still works. So when do I close the statement?

Comment: You need to researh `IDisposable`.

Comment: And search SO for "C# using". However, this might be a slightly more involved question. For instance, *in LINQ2SQL* the Dispose will close the connection *if and only if* it was *not* opened before-hand. I am not sure about EF. (So heed to the *general replies on `using`!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> a) Does the using statement open and then close a Sql connection on
>   the DbContext?

The variable declared inside `using` statement is Disposed when using block is ended. On DbContext the disposal method closes the connection, so as soon as that code block is ended the connection is closed.

> b) If so what happens with the second statement because i never
>   actually opened it and it still works. So when do I close the
>   statement?

Garbage collector clears the context object when it is no longer needed and the connection is being closed then.

You should read about [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) and [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx).

Comment: Yes, but will the Connection be closed? In all cases? Dispose will be called on the Context, but how is the Connection affected?

Comment: According to MSDN, it's not always true, that connection is closed by Dispose: 'The connection to the database (DbConnection object) is also disposed if it was created is by this context or ownership was passed to this context when this context was created.'

Comment: If you are on the default setup (and you wouldn't be asking this if you weren't :( ). What happens to the connection doesn't matter, read up about connection pooling as well.